# Optimal combination weights in table -- python 3

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, combinations

What kind of algorithm can I use to determine below question using python DataFrame.

```
Project      Bob    Mike    John
1            .7      .5     .6  
2            .2      .5     .1
3            .1       0     .3
```

Each decimal represents the level of interest each person has in a project. Assign ONE project to each person without repeating to maximize the decision (ie. sums the greatest total of all 3 assignments).

Any ideas? Pandas DataFrame please

Comment: This looks like an [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem). [`scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html) might be useful.